# how to save json value in sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend this is my JSON file `apitest[18318:207] { ErrorCode = 900; ErrorMessage = ""; Result = ( { DeviceInfoId = 12; Email = "rocky@itg.com"; FirstName = Rocky; LastName = Yadav; ProfileImage = "<null>"; ThumbnailImage = "<null>"; UserId = 153; } ); TokenID = 59nUniliob; isError = 0; }`

Can you please explain me how to parse the above JSON file and save the values in sqlite database this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SBJson parser](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) to get a dictionary/array out of a json (depending on your response). You can then get the individual values from the dictionary/array and save them into your database.

The git repo also has [some examples](https://github.com/stig/json-framework-examples) on how to use the parser.

Comment: Exactly what I was typing =].  One added bit would be to ensure that if this sqlite database is Core Data, ensure that there are no `nil` values before saving